# Smooth 2d rotation in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions, lerp

I'm trying to get an object to rotate smoothly on the z axis when it comes into contact with a collider. However it just seems to snap really quickly and I can't find a way to smooth this out.

I've split the rotation out into 2 scenarios - one for when the player enters the collider (which needs to be smooth), and one for when the player is already in the collider (which needs to be snappy). this is so that when the player enters the objects gravity (collider) he'll rotate smoothly before falling to the ground. However, if the player is already within the objects gravitational pull, its snappy so they can run on the ground (a circle) without any wierd floating or rolling occuring.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GravitationalBody : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 0.3f)] [SerializeField] private float m_OrientationSmoothing = 0.3f;  // How much to smooth out the movement

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D obj) {
        // Define direction of gravity
        Vector3 gravityDirection = transform.position - obj.transform.position;

        // apply gravity to all objects within range
        obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(gravityDirection);

        orientObjects(obj, gravityDirection, true);
    }

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D obj)
    {
        // Define direction of gravity
        Vector3 gravityDirection = transform.position - obj.transform.position;

        // apply gravity to all objects within range
        obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(gravityDirection);

        orientObjects(obj, gravityDirection, false);
    }

    // Control players Z axis rotation to point toward center of planets
    void orientObjects(Collider2D obj, Vector3 gravityDirection, bool lerp)
    {
        float orientation = 90 + Mathf.Atan2(gravityDirection.y, gravityDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        if (lerp)
        {
            Quaternion q = Quaternion.AngleAxis(orientation, Vector3.forward);
            obj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(obj.transform.rotation, q, m_OrientationSmoothing * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else obj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, orientation);
    }
}
```

Comment: `OnTriggerEnter2D` is only true for one physics tick before `OnTriggerStay2D` takes over. The conditions contradict each other.

Comment: You'd better rotate the object with `AddTorque`.

Comment: ah. so the reason the lerp isnt smoothing it from the `OnTriggerEnter2D` is because the `OnTriggerStay2D` is overriding it?

Comment: this is right. looking at it again with that perspective i can see the solution is using a bool to determin whether im entering a collider and should lerp, or whether im grounded or not

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help but if you want a smooth rotation look at this code, I'm sure you can find inspiration here:

```
[SerializeField] float _degreesPerSecond = 30f;
[SerializeField] Vector3 _axis = Vector3.forward;
void Update ()
{
 transform.Rotate( _axis.normalized * _degreesPerSecond * Time.deltaTime );
}
```